# Passing multiple models to a view using MVC3 and Ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, viewmodel

I'm new to MVC3 (which is why I bought a book on it, which is why I now have this question!), so apologies if there is an obvious answer to this!

I'm following a simple example of building a shopping cart in MVC3. The book advocates the use of Ninject for dependency injection, which I'm also new to. It all seems straight forward enough with one model, in this case Product, but building upon this I am struggling to add a second model and display this in the same view where the Product model is displayed. I've tried using a View Model but all examples I find wrap several classes into one model and I can't quite figure out how to implement this in my code.

The class:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Abstract Repository:

```
public interface IProductRepository
{
    IQueryable<Product> Products {get;}
}
```

Class to associate model with database:

```
public class EFDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products {get;set;}
}
```

Product Repository which implements abstract interface:

```
public class EFProductRepository : IProductRepository
{
    private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

    public IQueryable<Product> Products
    {
        get {return context.Products;}
    }
}
```

Ninject binds IProductRepository to EFProductRepository in a ControllerFactory class.

Controller:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    private IProductRepository repository;

    public ProductController(IProductRepository productRepository)
    {
        repository = productRepository;
    }

    public ViewResult List()
    {
        return View(repository.Products);
    }
}
```

My problem is passing repository.Products to the strongly typed view; if I need to pass another entity, which is very feasible how would I achieve this???

Answer (score 2):

You can build a ViewModel which looks like the following:

```
public class YourViewModel
{
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public List<OtherEntity> OtherEntities { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can wrap the repository in a service which contains all the methods
you need to fulfill your requests and/or businesslogic:

```
public class YourService
{
    private IProductRepository repository;

    public List<Product> GetAllProducts( )
    {
        return this.repository.Products.ToList( );
    }

    public List<OtherEntity> GetAllOtherEntites( )
    {
        return this.repository.OtherEntites.ToList( );
    }
}
```

and finally in the Controller you fill the ViewModel appropriately

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    private YourControllerService service = new YourControllerService( );
    // you can make also an IService interface like you did with
    // the repository

    public ProductController(YourControllerService yourService)
    {
        service = yourService;
    }

    public ViewResult List()
    {
         var viewModel = new YourViewModel( );
         viewModel.Products = service.GetAllProducts( );
         viewModel.OtherEntities = service.GetAllOtherEntities( );

        return View( viewModel );
    }
}
```

Now you have multiple entities on you ViewModel.

Comment: Could you please add how you would then use this in the view??

Comment: What is YourService and where should be add?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not directly answer to your question but it is connected.

If you correctly pass the model to view, you can handle it like this

```
@model SolutionName.WebUI.Models.YourViewModel

@Model.Product[index].ProductId
@Model.OtherEntity[index].OtherId
```

I know that it's old post but it maybe help others :)